# How far back does the window get pushed when calling the blur() method?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus

Does it go all the way to the back? Or does the window go to the back of the browser windows only? How does the functionality vary across browsers? I mean how far does it go back if you have a million other applications open with a million windows all over your desktop?

Comment: Wait, what? What do you mean when you say **back**?

Comment: I think your question has to be more descriptive. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Wait, what? What do you mean when you say **blur**?

Comment: Sorry, i mean how far does it go back if you have a million other applications open with a million windows. And is that consistent cross-browser?

Comment: Doesn't blur() just cause form fields to lose focus?

Comment: We don't know what you're talking about. "blur" is an event fired when an input control loses focus. "back" moves the browser address back through that window's history. It doesn't have anything to do with other applications, other windows, nothing.

Comment: Oh, you mean on a Window object. That might have been good to mention.

Comment: The blur() method can be used on the window object in IE to make a window go behind others. The focus() method brings the window to the front. I can't test other browsers at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other browsers don't change their z-order when you call the `blur()` method on the `window` object.  However, in Internet Explorer, the z-order is set to the lowest it can be - ie the window goes behind all other open, active windows, regardless of whether those windows are browser windows or other applications.

Note that Internet Explorer will not change the z-order of the window if there are other tabs open in the same window, so this *feature* is only really reliable for windows you open programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.blur()` does what you think it does. Here is some documentation I found on blur-related methods:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur
- http://api.jquery.com/blur/

It sounds like you think `blur()` would hide a window, but it is really related to an event that is triggered when an element on the page loses focus.

`element.blur()` seems to be a jQuery method that programmatically triggers the onBlur event for the element it is called on.

Comment: The blur() method in IE (IE), does push windows back, although it can be used for what you say as well.